# bash script fails with binary operator expected

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which checks for a paticular string and proceeds further but seems to be getting some error with binary operator expected

```
    local artifacts=$(realpath artifacts)/middle-end
    local env
    local account_id=${1}
    local branch_name=${2}
    local user_environments=${3}
    local gitlab_user_id=${4}
    env=$(ci/scripts/get-details-env.py -m "${user_environments}" -u "${user_id}")

    # Deploy to int1 from develop
    echo "$branch_name"
    if [ "${branch_name}" == "develop" ]; then
      env=brt-int;
    fi
    if [ "${branch_name}" =~ ^brt-rc-.* ]; then
      env=brt-uat;
    fi

    mkdir -p ${artifacts}
    cd middle-end
    ln -s ${NODE_PATH} ./node_modules
    npm run build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what your problem is, you must be using the new test operator `[[`. [http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031][bash new test details]

```
if [[ "${branch_name}" =~ ^atf-rc-.* ]]; then
              env=atf-stage1;
            fi
```

Comment: You can also avoid regex altogether by using globbing: `if [[ $ci_commit_ref_name = atf-rc-* ]]; then`